# CSS files and images not loading in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I tried to access the css in my index.jsp file using:

```
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/style.css">
```

I also tried using:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./resources/style.css">
```

[image]

but still the images and css file is not loading. When I tried to access the css file using:

```
localhost:8080/Project1_2/resources/style.css
```

It shows the error: HTTP Status 404 – Not Found

Do i need to include something in web.xml file?

Right now the xml file is :

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
 <display-name>Project1_2</display-name>
 <welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
   <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
   <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
   <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
   <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
   <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
 <filter>
   <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
   <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
   <init-param>
     <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
     <param-value>http://localhost:3306</param-value>
   </init-param>
 </filter>
 <filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>
 <servlet>
   <servlet-name>DummyServlet</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>com.project.DummyServlet</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>DummyServlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/dummy.do</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

They should be moved to WEB-INF instead of resources. WEB-INF is a directory where all web content is hold to be displayed on UI.